# Getting list view results from jsforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, code-documentation, jsforce

I'm able to get the results of a list view like so:

```
conn.sobject('ListView').retrieve(listId, function(err, listView) {
  console(listView);
});
```

But that only returns the description of the list view without the results and I want to get the results of the list view as well.

I see in the [docs here](https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/ListView.html) that there is a ListView class that has a `results` method, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Is there something I am missing? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` in API reference is not a sobject name to pass `Connection#sobject(sobjectName)`. It is a JavaScript class whose instance will be returned by `SObject#listview(listviewId)`. The available listview definitions of certain SObject are returned by calling `SObject#listviews()`.

```
conn.sobject("Account").listviews((err, ret) => {
    const listviewId = ret.listviews[0].id;
    conn.sobject("Account").listview(listviewId).results((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.records);
    });
});
```